# jquery reload my page on its own after a simple function, any idea why?

Tags: jquery

got a simple web site, in html. I do a simple function to move the image a user click to a different div ;

```
function setimage(){
 $(".moving_img").click(function(){
  $('#target').after( $(this));
 });
}
```

but, after having moved the image ( also added a background change to yellow just to confirm it worked), my page suddenly reloads, console wont show me any errors, and I dont know what could cause this reload ...  any idea why ? theres no ajax or any server-side code or any complicated pluggin I used ( i created everything I used and I'm no pro)

Comment: Is your .moving_img element inside a form? And what kind of element is it?

Comment: not its not in a form, and its either a div or an img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setimage(){
 $(".moving_img").click(function(){
  $('#target').after( $(this));
  return false; // add return false to prevent this.
 });
}
```

Or use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
function setimage(){
 $(".moving_img").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#target').after( $(this));
 });
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, I pass so much time trying to figure out how do stop this :)

I've been wondering why I saw alot of e.stopPropagation in plugings source code and such !